# Zabbix - Checking all values on a given day

Tags: zabbix

I have a defined item that runs from 6:00 a.m. to 9:00 a.m. every 30 minutes and checks whether a given process is running at that time.
This returns the results:

```
None
None
exist
None
...
```

Is there any simple way to write a trigger expression that will check if all values are "None" on a given day?
If so, then the message should be displayed.
I'm currently using last() <> "exist". But I don't like it because the process may end faster and then, for example, at 08:30 a message appears that the process is not running. This is true, but the process was working before, it just ended.
Can anyone help?